# How to alter number of row and label of webform Matrix Component

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

Using Drupal 7 webform and Webform Matrix Component in their last stable versions, I have a Matrix in a webform, this Matrix has 2 elements, first one is label, second one is textfield.

How can I alter the webform to change the number of row of this matrix, and the label of each row?

Imagine I want as many row as the number of line return by a sql request, and the label, the value of each line of this request.

Thank you very much!

Comment: For exemple, for some of my grid component, I use this: 
    
    $new_grid_questions = array();
    $new_grid_questions = db_query("SELECT data,data FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE nid = 42 AND sid = '$sid' AND cid IN (82,83)")->fetchAllKeyed();
    $element['#grid_questions'] = $new_grid_questions;
    
  }